# Adding values based on the year

Tags: r

```
id   product            id2     year   cost 
 1  biscuits    202-55-3041     2017      2 
 2  biscuits    903-36-9457     2014      2 
 3  biscuits    938-33-7254     2014      2 
 4  biscuits    739-29-5963     2017      2 
 5  biscuits    731-49-5483     2017      2 
 6  biscuits    892-15-2567     2018      2 
 7  biscuits    518-79-7674     2017      2 
 8  biscuits    305-63-7908     2017      2
```

This is my current data set the name of this data is called 'total1'

I am a beginner in R and I was wondering if there was a way to add up the cost of the product based on the year, for example;

In 2017 there were 10 biscuits sold

In 2018 there were 8 biscuits sold

I am trying to determine which is the least profitable year in terms of biscuits sold.

I apologise if this is answered elsewhere if it is direct me thank you.

Comment: Why were there 8 biscuits sold in 2018?

Comment: This data is simplified from the original data set. The original data has 6500 obs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the number of sold items is stored in column `cost`, here's a simple solution using `tapply`:

```
tapply(total1$cost, total1$year, sum)
2014 2017 2018 
   4   10    2
```

Another simple solution is by using `aggregate`:
**Edit:** 
thanks to @Darren Tsai's comment, the code here is simplified:

```
aggregate(cost ~ year, total1, sum)
  total1$year total1$cost
1        2014           4
2        2017          10
3        2018           2
```

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to turn this information into a graph?

Comment: Would a barchart be helpful?

Comment: yeah it would, if you know how?

Comment: Ver simple: 1. store the sums in a dataframe: `df <- tapply(total1$cost, total1$year, sum)` and barplot `df`:
`barplot(df, xlab = "Year", ylab = "Number of sales")`

Comment: Curious to see that the answer was voted down but accepted by the OP ;)

Comment: The formula part should be simplified to `cost ~ year` because you have set `data = total1` in `aggregate`.

Comment: Okay, rather than downvoting the answer you could have suggested I improve the code along this line. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks Chris appreciate the help!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Yes it doesn't deserve a downvote. I did that for two reasons. (1) There may exist other products except for biscuits, so the summation should be based on `product` and `year`. Of course, the OP emphasizes "based on the year" and doesn't specify whether there exist other products or not. I think an assumption based on `product` and `year` will be more general and reasonable. i.e. `aggregate(cost ~ product + year, total1, sum)` (2) This question obviously is duplicate and should be closed. You can flag it and don't need to answer it again.

Comment: Do feel free to click the upward arrow if the answer was useful to your query. Also note @Darren Tsai's perfectly reasonable point about there potentially being other products than just biscuits and, if that is the case, the code he is proposing.